# How to output Recess data as a Json?

Tags: php, rest, ember.js, recess

I've installed Recess:

http://www.recessframework.org/

Configured the database, added a table, generated model and controller.

In video tutorial you can see author uses URI like ../something.json to get JSON results. I generated a profile class so i navigate to ../profile.json, but get an error:

```
Unable to provide desired content-type. Does the view XXX exist?
```

Basically what i need is a proper formed Restful JSON service for a use in Ember.js.

I would love it if Recess return JSON without adding .json.

Have anyone of you know how to make it work? 
How to make a JSON Restful service with Recess properly?

Recess forum is down, so you are only help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the controller class to allow it output data in JSON format

```
/**
 * !RespondsWith Json, Layouts
 * !Prefix something/
 */
```

If you want to get rid of adding .json to the request URL - just leave Json as a single possible output:

```
/**
 * !RespondsWith Json
 * !Prefix something/
 */
```

See [this link](http://www.recessframework.org/page/recess-php-content-negotiation) for the details

On the other hand, you are able to force the JSON output using `Accept: application/json` header in your HTTP requests, so no .json word should be added to the request URL. However, you still need to enable the Json output in your controller class.